# Redirect to Admin Panel(Superuser) Login Page from views.py and template in Django

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I am trying to keep a link of Django's prebuilds admin pannel on my website.

My Project's `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('diagnosis.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin'),
]
```

In Template:

```
<a href="{% url 'admin' %}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary px-6">Explore Admin Pannel!</a>
```

But it gives errors like:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'admin' not found. 'admin' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

How can I fix this?

I also tried redirecting to admin in `views.py` like:

```
if (condition):
        return redirect('admin')
```

This approach also does not work. How can I redirect in admin pannel from views.py also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `admin:index` instead of `admin`.

In a template:

```
<a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary px-6">Explore Admin Pannel!</a>
```

In a view:

```py
if (condition):
    return redirect('admin:index')
```